# How do I access some sort of OnLoad event in Word 2007 VBA?

Tags: vba, ms-word, ms-office

I am trying to have some code fire when the document is first loaded, but there are two problems.  First, I don't know which method to call to get something to fire when the document is first opened.  Second, if they have macros disabled, how can I be sure that it gets called when they are enabled?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Document_Open` event is sent when your document is first loaded. To make use of it, enter the following in the VBA code for `ThisDocument`:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()

    '// your code goes here'

End Sub
```

As for the disabled macros, I'm not aware of a method that will be called as soon as macros are enabled.

Comment: Thanks, that should help!

As for the disabled macro's I will figure something out I suppose.